# Spark Split RDD into chunks and concatenate

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a relatively simple problem.

I have an large Spark RDD[String] (containing JSON). In my use case I want to group (concatenate) N strings together into a new RDD[String], so that it will have the size of oldRDD.size/N.

pseudo example:

```
 val oldRDD : RDD[String] = ['{"id": 1}', '{"id": 2}', '{"id": 3}', '{"id": 4}']

 val newRDD : RDD[String] = someTransformation(oldRDD, ",", 2)
 newRDD = ['{"id": 1},{"id": 2}','{"id": 3},{"id": 4}']

 val anotherRDD : RDD[String] = someTransformation(oldRDD, ",", 3)
 anotherRDD = ['{"id": 1},{"id": 2},{"id": 3}','{"id": 4}']
```

I already looked for a similar case, but couldnt find anything.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you have to use zipWithIndex function and then calculate group.

For example, index = 3 and n (number of groups) = 2 gives you 2nd group. 3 / 2 = 1 (integer divide), so 0-based 2nd group

```
val n = 3;
val newRDD1 = oldRDD.zipWithIndex() // creates tuples (element, index)
    // map to tuple (group, content)
    .map(x => (x._2 / n, x._1))
    // merge
    .reduceByKey(_ + ", " + _)
    // remove key
    .map(x => x._2)
```

One note: order of "zipWithIndex" is internal order. It can make no sense in business logic, you must check if order is ok in your case. If not, sort RDD and then use zipWithIndex

Comment: This is a great answer! But `n` in this case will not be the number of groups; instead it is the *size* of the groups. If you want `n` to be the *number* of groups, you would need to use modulo operator instead of division, and take note that the ordering of elements would not be preserved.